# Changing default image resize dimensions in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I modify the core Wordpress files so that I can specify different default dimensions for the image resizing function in posts? For instance I'd like the 'Medium' option to have a default width of 400px instead of 300px.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to do it via core wordpress files? You can do it through the UI by going to Settings | Media | Image Sizes.

Comment: You can do it programmatically too if you are creating say your own wordpress theme. Too much to get into here, but you can see this WP codex document - http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails